# Export Grease Pencil to Godot

Tags: export, grease-pencil

I quite like the artistic style of the *Grease Pencil* tool and would like to make a game in a similar style with Godot.

If I, for example draw a cube like this:

[image]

And export it as *Collada* and import it in Godot it won't work, because it is not a mesh.

[image]

If, however, I convert this to a *Polygon Curve* and change the *Geometry > Depth* and then export this as *Collada* and import it in Godot it is obviously not the result I am looking for:

[image]

Is there a way to export *Grease Pencil* directly with texture or convert it somehow into a textured mesh from the drawings?